# Regular expression | Notepad | Search for whole XML Tag with specified content and select it

Tags: regex, xml

With the regular expression below I get the single XML element "lesson".

```
(.*?)<lesson id=(.*)[\s\S]*?<\/lesson>
```

But how can I search for an XML element with a specific content and mark the whole XML element "lesson" in Notepad++, therewith I can copy the XML element in another file.

Find and mark the XML Element "lesson" with the following content:

```
<assigned_day>5</assigned_day>
```

**XML Example**

```
<lesson id="LS_18300">
  <periods>2</periods>
  <lesson_subject id="SU_Gs"/>
  <lesson_teacher id="TR_Kl"/>
  <lesson_classes id="CL_MM4A"/>
  <teacher_value>200000</teacher_value>
  <effectivebegindate>20170814</effectivebegindate>
  <effectiveenddate>20180706</effectiveenddate>
  <block>2</block>
  <occurence>11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFFF1111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF1F111FF111FFFF11111FFF1111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111F</occurence>
  <times>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>1</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>10</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>1520</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>1605</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_E13"/>
    </time>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>1</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>11</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>1615</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>1700</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_E13"/>
    </time>
  </times>
</lesson>
<lesson id="LS_18400">
  <periods>1</periods>
  <lesson_subject id="SU_Finw"/>
  <lesson_teacher id="TR_Cp"/>
  <lesson_classes id="CL_MM4B"/>
  <teacher_value>100000</teacher_value>
  <effectivebegindate>20170814</effectivebegindate>
  <effectiveenddate>20180706</effectiveenddate>
  <occurence>11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFFF1111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF1F111FF111FFFF11111FFF1111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111F</occurence>
  <times>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>4</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>5</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>1100</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>1145</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_113"/>
    </time>
  </times>
</lesson>
<lesson id="LS_23200">
  <periods>3</periods>
  <lesson_subject id="SU_W+G"/>
  <lesson_teacher id="TR_Mü"/>
  <lesson_classes id="CL_E3B"/>
  <teacher_value>300000</teacher_value>
  <effectivebegindate>20170814</effectivebegindate>
  <effectiveenddate>20180706</effectiveenddate>
  <block>3</block>
  <occurence>11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFFF1111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF1F111FF111FFFF11111FFF1111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111F</occurence>
  <times>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>4</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>3</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>0910</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>0955</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_E14"/>
    </time>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>4</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>4</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>1010</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>1055</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_E14"/>
    </time>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>4</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>5</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>1100</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>1145</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_E14"/>
    </time>
  </times>
</lesson>
<lesson id="LS_25000">
  <periods>2</periods>
  <lesson_subject id="SU_De"/>
  <lesson_teacher id="TR_Bt"/>
  <lesson_classes id="CL_M3A"/>
  <teacher_value>200000</teacher_value>
  <effectivebegindate>20170814</effectivebegindate>
  <effectiveenddate>20180706</effectiveenddate>
  <block>2</block>
  <occurence>11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFFF1111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF1F111FF111FFFF11111FFF1111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111F</occurence>
  <times>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>5</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>3</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>0910</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>0955</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_226"/>
    </time>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>5</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>4</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>1010</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>1055</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_226"/>
    </time>
  </times>
</lesson>
<lesson id="LS_25200">
  <periods>2</periods>
  <lesson_subject id="SU_FRW"/>
  <lesson_teacher id="TR_Md"/>
  <lesson_classes id="CL_M3A"/>
  <teacher_value>200000</teacher_value>
  <effectivebegindate>20170814</effectivebegindate>
  <effectiveenddate>20180706</effectiveenddate>
  <block>2</block>
  <occurence>11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111FFFF1111FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11111FF1F111FF111FFFF11111FFF1111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF11111FF1111F</occurence>
  <times>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>4</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>1</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>0730</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>0815</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_114"/>
    </time>
    <time>
      <assigned_day>4</assigned_day>
      <assigned_period>2</assigned_period>
      <assigned_starttime>0820</assigned_starttime>
      <assigned_endtime>0905</assigned_endtime>
      <assigned_room id="RM_114"/>
    </time>
  </times>
</lesson>
```

One try was like that:

```
(.*?)<lesson id=(.*)[\s\S]*?(assigned_day>5)?<\/lesson>
```

Comment: You should really be using XPath or XSL for this.  A simple regex won't handle nested XML well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
<lesson\s+id[^>]*>(?=(?:(?!<\/lesson>).)*<assigned_day>5<\/assigned_day>).*?<\/lesson>
```

**p.s:** make sure that ._matches newline is checked in your notepad++ editor

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K2zCNv/5)

Comment: But do be aware that when you try processing XML using regular expressions, your code will ALWAYS be wrong, in that there will be either false positives or false negatives if the XML isn't exactly as you expect it.

Comment: You are right, but usually regex is used when you know the target set of the data that needs to be processed just like preparing a dress from tailor with exact measurement. In fact, no regex is right over wrong data set ,be it xml or not !

Comment: Yes, but we get an awful lot of people on SO struggling to format their XML exactly the way a receiving application expects it, simply because the receiving application doesn't take the trouble to use a real XML parser.